# Change Tracking in an Azure SQL DB for Azure Search for non-dbo Schema

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I am associating an Azure SQL DB Table to my Azure Search using an Indexer. I am setting this all up using Azure's website: https://portal.azure.com

When I try and create the Indexer in Azure Search, I get the warning about "Consider enabling integrated change tracking on your database." However, I have enabled integrated change tracking on my database and table.

I have successfully setup several tables this way, in the same database, and they're working just fine with Azure Search. However, this table has a schema other than [dbo], and the others with change tracking were [dbo]. The same SQL user is being used for all the tables, and it has been granted the change tracking permission to this table, too.

Is there a problem with the Azure website where I cannot do this via the UI? Can this be done otherwise? Is there a permission issue with my DB's schema? Something else?

Because of this warning, I have not actually created this Azure Search Index.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of Azure Search portal - it doesn't support enabling integrated change tracking for non-default schemas. The workaround is to create the indexer programmatically, using REST API or .NET SDK. For a walkthrough, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers.

Comment: was this mentioned any where `It's a limitation of Azure Search portal `